# Extension exists but uuid_generate_v4 fails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

At amazon ec2 RDS Postgresql:

```
=> SHOW rds.extensions;

rds.extensions                                                                                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 btree_gin,btree_gist,chkpass,citext,cube,dblink,dict_int,dict_xsyn,earthdistance,fuzzystrmatch,hstore,intagg,intarray,isn,ltree,pgcrypto,pgrowlocks,pg_trgm,plperl,plpgsql,pltcl,postgis,postgis_tiger_geocoder,postgis_topology,sslinfo,tablefunc,tsearch2,unaccent,uuid-ossp
(1 row)
```

As you can see, `uuid-ossp` extension does exist. However, when I'm calling the function for generation `uuid_v4`, it fails:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    name character varying(32) NOT NULL,

);
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: In future, please always show the **exact text** of any error message.

Comment: Yes extension exists but database is probably in inconsistent state. One reason that may happen is if you drop the schema but leave the extension. To avoid this it's good tactic to run
DROP EXTENSION  IF EXISTS "uuid-ossp" CASCADE;
and then
CREATE EXTENSION  "uuid-ossp";
(see detailed explanation in the answer of @atomCode below)

Answer (score 468, accepted):

The extension is *available* but not *installed* in this database.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: Just to be clear, to select the db one can write `\c <db name>` in the pgsql console

Comment: @CraigRinger Where I can find this doc?

Comment: When running \c <dbname> in pgsql console, I got an authentication error. I managed to work around it using the Ubuntu command line. `sudo -u postgres psql <db_name>` <br> From there I just run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";` as instructed.

Comment: I got error 'ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory'

Answer (score 46):

If the extension is already there but you don't see the uuid_generate_v4() function when you do a describe functions ***\df*** command then all you need to do is drop the extension and re-add it so that the functions are also added. Here is the issue replication:

```
db=# \df
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  extension "uuid-ossp" already exists
DROP EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
db=# \df
                                  List of functions
 Schema |        Name        | Result data type |    Argument data types    |  Type
--------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------------+--------
 public | uuid_generate_v1   | uuid             |                           | normal
 public | uuid_generate_v1mc | uuid             |                           | normal
 public | uuid_generate_v3   | uuid             | namespace uuid, name text | normal
 public | uuid_generate_v4   | uuid             |                           | normal

db=# select uuid_generate_v4();
           uuid_generate_v4
--------------------------------------
 b19d597c-8f54-41ba-ba73-02299c1adf92
(1 row)
```

What probably happened is that the extension was originally added to the cluster at some point in the past and then you probably created a new database within that cluster afterward. If that was the case then the new database will only be "aware" of the extension but it will not have the uuid functions added which happens when you add the extension. Therefore you must re-add it.

Comment: Yes I had that problem too and what you describe here fixed it

Answer (score 27):

Looks like the extension is not installed in the particular database you require it.

You should connect to this particular database with

```
 \CONNECT my_database
```

Then install the extension in this database

```
 CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: it should be  psql <your_dbName> then  paste this CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

Answer (score 23):

## Step #1: re-install uuid-ossp extention into the exact schema:

If this is a fresh installation you can skip `SET` and `DROP`. Credits to @atomCode ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007661/601844))

```
SET search_path TO public;
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA public;
```

After this, you should see **uuid_generate_v4()** function IN THE RIGHT SCHEMA *(when execute `\df` query in *psql* command-line prompt)*.

## Step #2: use fully-qualified names (with `schemaname.` qualifier):

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
```

Comment: thank you. i created first by droping and created extension with schema but it didn't work, Next i went to default and write schema.uuid_generate_v4() which did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

If you've changed the `search_path`, specify the `public` schema in the function call:

```sql
public.uuid_generate_v4()
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

```
create extension IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" schema pg_catalog version "1.1";
```

make sure the extension should by on pg_catalog and not in your schema...

Answer (score 7):

Just add this code to the Beginning of your script

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It was the same I was facing. The `uuid_generate_v4` was from the `public` schema and I was trying to run it in a specific schema, so to fix it I did:

```
SET search_path TO specific_schema;

INSERTO INTO my_table VALUES public.uuid_generate_v4();
```

You can check the schema where your function is running:

```
\df uuid_generate_v4
```

Or

```
SELECT n.nspname, p.probin, p.proname
FROM
    pg_proc p
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE p.proname like 'uuid_generate_v4';
```

You can check info related to the extension of the uuid-ossp like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname LIKE 'uuid-ossp';
```

You can add this extension case you don't have it already:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do it from unix command (apart from PGAdmin) dont forget to pass the DB as a parameter. otherwise this extension will not be enabled when executing requests on this DB

psql -d  -c "create EXTENSION pgcrypto;"

Answer (score 0):

in my case were 3 steps. Create the database, connect to the database and create the extension. The important step is the second one, "connect to the database", and you can notice the line without ";" cause is a command and not a SQL sentence.

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name_here;
\connect database_name_here 
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this here incase it might help. I was working on a nestjs app which uses typeorm. When I tried running migrations I got the error below:

> error: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist

After reading through all responses and trying different things,
I ran this block of code to install the extention if it does not exist:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

Then I ran `SELECT uuid_generate_v4();` which returned a positive response. But I tried running the migrations again and it still failed. Then I ran this code below:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v4() RETURNS uuid AS $$ SELECT uuid_generate_v4(); $$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;`

The above step creates a uuid_generate_v4() function that simply calls the real postgres function under the hood.

Then I ran this also

`GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION uuid_generate_v4() TO username;`

Replace `username` with your postgres username

Then when I tried the migrations again, it worked.

Comment: Weird. I have the same issue locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

If the above steps don't resolve the issue, consider installing the uuid-ossp extension using the package manager on your system. On many Linux distributions, it can be installed with a command like:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib   # For Debian/Ubuntu

sudo yum install postgresql-contrib   # For Red Hat/CentOS
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still encountering this issue, here are two solutions:

The first solution involves enabling the uuid-ossp extension in your PostgreSQL database. Use the following SQL command:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

For the second solution, use the @BeforeInsert() decorator from TypeORM and the uuid npm package. Change your ID from @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') to simply @PrimaryColumn(). Then, append to the end of your entity class:

```
@BeforeInsert()
generateUuid() {
  if (!this.id) {
    this.id = uuidv4();
  }
}
```

This ensures that a UUID is generated from your application using the uuid package.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers provides exact steps (for the people who are not experienced much) to resolve issue.

Here are the steps:

1. In terminal(I'm on Linux/Debian), access your PostgreSQL database through running: `sudo -u postgres psql <db_name>`
2. Then run following command. `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

All credit goes to @[Joachim Rives](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11048997/joachim-rives). He provided answer as comment under @Craig Ringer's post.